# Unable to access local development server of Google Cloud SDK for Python from Vagrant

Tags: google-app-engine, vagrant, google-app-engine-python

I am running  local development server in a Vagrant box and trying to open it in Chrome(host machine). But it fails to open in the host machine. Using the `curl` on localhost:7000 in the guest machine returns the HTML content. This is my Vagrant file

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "setup_dev_env.sh"

  config.vm.box_check_update = false

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 7080, host: 7080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 7000, host: 7000, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  config.vm.synced_folder "SOME_PATH", "/home/vagrant/code"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = false
    vb.memory = "4096"
  end
end
```

Command to run the server(guest machine):

```
python /home/vagrant/code/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py PATH_TO_app.yaml --port=7080 --admin_port=7000  --datastore_path=~/BLAH.db
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the following when running your command (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/tools/local-devserver-command)

> --host=...
>
> The host address to use for the server. You may need to set this to be able to access the development server from another computer on
>   your network. An address of `0.0.0.0` allows both localhost access and
>   IP or hostname access. Default is `localhost`.

In your case as running in vagrant, you need to make sure its bound to `0.0.0.0`

```
python /home/vagrant/code/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py \
PATH_TO_app.yaml \
--host=0.0.0.0 --port=7080 --admin_port=7000  --datastore_path=~/BLAH.db
```